# Outbound port 25 cannot telnet

Tags: debian, iptables, ufw

Hopefully this isn't just another "Port 25 blocked" question. My situation is slightly different.

I have 2 accounts with hosting company X.

Account 1: Ubuntu box *can* telnet to given.domain.com 25 (or for examples sake Port 80)

Account 2: Debian box *cannot* telnet to given.domain.com 25 but **can** port 80

I usually use Ubuntu so installed UFW on Debian and have the following UFW status:

```
25                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
25 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Additionally I ran

`iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT`

And have also done a reboot.

**My host is not blocking Port 25** as the Ubuntu box clearly shows but what would stop telnet from accessing port 25 if the firewalls and active and the provider allows it?

Additionally I have spun a blank Debian 10 instance and it was able to telnet fine to the same given.domain.com 25

I have also run `iptables -F` (which of course booted me out) and also stopped the UFW service - but again - neither worked. If it mattered - I am additionally running as root.

Comment: What is the name of the hosting company?

Comment: Guess it doesn't hurt to say - its Linode

Comment: Linode blocks outbound SMTP on new accounts. You need to contact them.

Comment: I have raised a ticket with them but on another Debian box within the same account I am able to telnet on port 25. `aauser@AA-01:~$ telnet reception.mail-tester.com 25
Trying 94.23.206.89...
Connected to reception.mail-tester.com.
Escape character is '^]'.` on `Linux AA-01 4.19.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.98-1 (2020-01-26) x86_64`

Comment: use `tcpdump` to see if the packet leaves the system when using telnet. If it was blocked by any system's firewall, tcpdump would simply not capture it. This allows to remove doubts on a possible cause by doing a measurement and not assuming anything else was done or not done correctly. `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT` is useless for *outbound*, since it' an INPUT (= inbound) rule

Answer (score 0):

As expected this was Linode blocking the server. Apparently all new servers are blocked by default on Port 25 (even though I spun a new instance which worked!!). Obviously after time Port 25 is enabled - I'm not sure how long that is!